# Julia: Evaluate expressions from a dictionary

Tags: julia

I have a list of expressions, f.x

```
"a1 || a4"
"a3 && a5
```

and a dictionary with the truth values of these

```
a1 -> true
a2 -> false
```

I need to evaluate expressions from the list, with the true/false values from the dictionary

Any ideas how this can be achieved easily? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Is performance important?  Is the list of expressions fixed? Are they being evaluated with different sets of input values? Are they only boolean values? If the expressions are being reused, then you might want to parse them once, and store the Exprs, instead of parsing them every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like there might be a more elegant solution but this will certainly get the job done.

```julia
truths = Dict("a1" => true, "a2" => false)
expressions = ["a1 || a4", "a1 && a2"]

for (key, value) in truths
    info("evaluating: '$key = $value'")
    eval(parse("$key = $value"))
end

for exp in expressions
    info("$exp => $(eval(parse(exp)))")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

What is `f.x`?  What do you mean by a list? In future, please give working code, not code snippets like this.

In Julia you almost certainly do not want to store Julia code like `a1 || a4` in strings, but rather as Julia expressions (which is what `parse` of a string actually gives):

```
ex = [:(a1 || a4), :(a3 && a5)]
```

Secondly, you probably don't want to use variables with names like this, but rather an array:

```
a = bitrand(5)   # 5 random bits
a[1]   # gives true
```

Then you would use

```
ex = [:(a[1] || a[4]), :(a[3] && [a[5])]
```

and you can just do

```
map(eval, ex)
```

which evaluates each expression in the vector.

If you think that using `a[1]` instead of `a1` is too much typing, you can walk the syntax tree and replace `a_i` with `a[i]`. Or, if you have the strings, just use the `replace` function on the string:

```
replace("hello a3 a34", "a3", "a[3]")
```

(so be careful!)

Comment: Sorry I was trying to type it up as generally as possible. The srting expressions are read in to a type from a JSON file and represent genes that are knocked out (if you know your biology) and the entire list needs to be evaluated frequently